# What is the path to the files on this external hard drive connected via a USB adapter?

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive, filesystem

I'm not seeing a hard drive [connected](https://askubuntu.com/q/517586/847449) through an external USB adapter:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0461:3f41 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Wired Desktop 320K Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro XM102K Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 002 Device 018: ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS578 SATA 6Gb/s
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ls /mnt/
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

but `fdisk -l` shows the drive:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 74.53 GiB, 80026361856 bytes, 156301488 sectors
Disk model: AS              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6FF2FD37-7327-48AF-BFC1-224378E567DC

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2     4096   1054719   1050624  513M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  1054720 156301311 155246592   74G Linux LVM
```

How do I find the path to read and write files as a larger USB thumb drive?

I was expecting to see the drive in the GUI as a thumb drive but it's not visible there.

here is the dmesg output:

https://gist.github.com/NICKSAUNDERS/107c7d373bc5f17f66fadcf67639ca00

Comment: Are you sure the hard drive has enough power to run? If you're not seeing it, but it's spinning, then the external device may not have enough power to properly initialise and announce itself to the OS.

Comment: This USB adapter has its own power supply for which it connects to an outlet.  I tried a few drives so think it's more a setting or something I'm doing wrong.  I followed the directions on the sequence to connect the wires, of course.

Comment: it's an LVM partition and logical volume.  That won't show as a flash drive.  You'll ahve to check under `/dev/mapper` and `sudo lvs` to find the logical volumes on your `/dev/sdb` to mount those, and then mount that to `/mnt/`