# How to mount an LVM formatted hard drive connected through a USB adapter?

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, external-hdd, lvm

What would be the [standard directory](https://superuser.com/q/116617/977796) to create for an [external](https://askubuntu.com/q/1469319/847449) hard LVM hard drive?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ls /dev/mapper
control  vgubuntu-root  vgubuntu-swap_1
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo lvs
  LV     VG       Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   vgubuntu -wi-a----- <73.07g                                                    
  swap_1 vgubuntu -wi-a----- 980.00m                                                    
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ls /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo vgscan
  Found volume group "vgubuntu" using metadata type lvm2
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

And how would such a drive be mounted?

Is it automatically:

```
$ sudo vgchange -ay VolGroup00
```

and then:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /mnt/fcroot -o ro,user
```

I would want it writable, so I would think to exchange `ro` above for `rw`.  But where did VolGroup00 come from?  I tried running `vgscan` with a higher verbosity without useful result.

Context and some condensed explanation of the workings of LVM appreciated.

additional data:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vgubuntu/root' [<73.07 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vgubuntu/swap_1' [980.00 MiB] inherit
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

---

I believe this might be termed "importing into the volume group" but am not certain.